# Having trouble with multiple queries in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm trying to combine 2 queries into one formula so the 2nd query always shows below the first

Query 1 :

```
QUERY('Input Monday'!A4:J201,"SELECT A, B, C, D, F, G, H, I, J WHERE ((lower(A) = 'h&h')) AND ((lower(D) != 'melbourne'))")
```

Query 2 :

```
QUERY('Home and Host input'!A2:M100,"SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K WHERE ((A = datetime '"&TEXT(SATURDAY!B1,"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'))")
```

Both work fine on their own although when i combine them i either get a parse error, or an `array_litteral error`

Does anyone know have any tips or know of another way for a 2nd query to find the bottom row of the first query then add it to the next row?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Can you show a copy of your sheet with the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

to put them under each other both needs to have equal amount of columns. try:

```
={QUERY('Input Monday'!A4:J201,
 "select A,B,C,D,F,G,H,I,J,' ','  ' 
  where lower(A) = 'h&h' 
    and lower(D) != 'melbourne'
  label ' ''','  '''");
 QUERY('Home and Host input'!A2:M100,
 "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K 
  where A = datetime '"&TEXT(SATURDAY!B1, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'")}
```